# Psipred installation

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install psipred in a unix server.

Psipred is installed, but fails because it can not find the correct database files.  I have downloaded uniprod90.fasta. Psipred also loads the old legacy ncbi BLAST-2.2.26 and BLAST+.
`runpsipred` and `runpsipredplus` have been patched to call the correct version of BLAST.

I have run a few commands to index the uniprod90 database:

```
pfilt uniref90.fasta > uniref90filt
formatdb -t uniref90filt -i uniref90filt
makeblastdb -in uniref90.fasta -dbtype prot -input_type fasta -out uniref90.fasta
```

I then ran `psipred` and got this error:

```
$ ./psipred/example/example.fasta
Running PSI-BLAST with sequence  ./psipred/example/example.fasta ...
[blastpgp] WARNING: Unable to open uniref90.pin
[blastpgp] WARNING: Unable to open uniref90.pin
FATAL: Error whilst running blastpgp - script terminated!
```

`makeblastdb` created 26 pin files, but not uniref90.pin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
makeblastdb -in uniref90.fasta -dbtype prot -input_type fasta -out uniref90
```

The `-out` is the name of the DB. So if you use `uniref90.fasta`, it creates uniref90.fasta.pin`while the script seems to be expecting`uniref90.pin`.